# How to make ruby logout link work in nginx reverse proxy environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, reverse-proxy

First of all, I already asked the same question on serverfault but it doesn't seem to be attracting much attention, hence the repost on here. If this is conceptually wrong, please let me know and I'll happily take the advised action.

I have a few internal web services, redmine servers to be precise, which I want to expose to other subnets and over the internet. I believe the VirtualBox/docker aspects of the architecture is not directly relevant as all the linking and port forwarding seems to work but here is how the network looks like.

```
Router/external-dynamic-ip/ddns-hostname:8090 -> 
Lan Host/192.168.0.6/10.0.2.2:8090 -> VirtualBox/10.0.2.15
vbox:8090 -> docker-nginx(NAT)/172.17.0.6:80

vbox:8080 -> docker-redmine-tech(NAT)/172.17.0.4:3000

vbox:8081 -> docker-redmine-tech(NAT)/172.17.0.5:3000
```

With the nginx config below, I can access the docker-redmine-tech service via the web browser on a different machine on the LAN as `http://192.168.0.6:8090/tech/`. Homepage, images, scripts and all the navigation after logging in seems to work just fine, also the address bar base url always stays as `http://192.168.0.6:8090/tech/`, so, redirections are invisible to the user.

```
http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    log_format upstreamlog '[$time_local] $request_uri $http_referer $http_host $host $server_port $proxy_host $proxy_port $remote_addr - $remote_user - $server_name to: $upstream_addr $http_x_forwarded_for: $status / upstream $upstream_status $request upstream_response_time $upstream_response_time msec $msec request_time $request_time body: $request_body';

    access_log      /var/log/nginx/access.log upstreamlog;
    error_log       /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;
    rewrite_log on;
    underscores_in_headers on;

    upstream redmine-tech {
            server 10.0.2.15:8080;
    }

    server {
            listen 80 default_server;

            location /tech/ {
                    proxy_set_header Host $http_host/tech;
                    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                    proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                    proxy_redirect    off;
                    add_header Pragma "no-cache";
                    add_header Cache-Control "no-cache";

                    proxy_pass http://redmine-tech/;
                    sub_filter 'action="/'  'action="/tech/';
                    sub_filter 'href="/'  'href="/tech/';
                    sub_filter 'src="/'  'src="/tech/';
                    sub_filter_once off;
            }
    }
}
```

The redmine web pages seem to use relative urls , hence the sub_filter rewrites. This doesn't break any absolute urls like `http://www.redmine.org/guide` either.

So far so good. The only issue I have is with `logout`. When I hit logout, this takes me to `http://192.168.0.6` but I expect to be on `http://192.168.0.6:8090/tech/` instead.

The `html` code of the logout form is

```
<form action="/tech/logout" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="cJAHHZxZ0ddFKXSz+vzDze3N4V3yhcxfH/bM0u2IcZJXpsnBBpAr9I4v8U9yLopSpra3WkhB4oOMIqgM7iXE9w==" />
```

This is the nginx log after hitting `logout`.

```
[08/Nov/2016:13:41:23 +0000] /tech/logout http://192.168.0.6:8090/tech/logout 192.168.0.6:8090 192.168.0.6 80 redmine-tech 80 10.0.2.2 - - -  to: 10.0.2.15:8080 -: 302 / upstream 302 POST /tech/logout HTTP/1.1 upstream_response_time 0.011 msec 1478612483.524 request_time 0.011 body: _method=post&authenticity_token=Hb1wtuM6oSTWbgTG%2B2Ldr%2BXZZYbv6awGzDIFa7vkv6xqQDvRtuWAnCr4vDrb1SpQP8kl6qVvcuP03LGY%2ByX9rQ%3D%3D
```

I am using redmine with ruby on rails and the `/logout` link seems to have been auto generated by ruby. The `find . -name "*.rb" -exec grep -Hn "You are being" {} \;` search returns the following result

```
./usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-4.2.7.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/redirection.rb:40:        body = %(<html><body>You are being <a href="#{ERB::Util.unwrapped_html_escape(uri.to_s)}">redirected</a>.</body></html>)
./usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-4.2.7.1/lib/action_controller/metal/redirecting.rb:76:      self.response_body = "<html><body>You are being <a href=\"#{ERB::Util.unwrapped_html_escape(location)}\">redirected</a>.</body></html>"
```

I am not sure which `rb` file actually runs in this case, but seems like it is the uri/location conversion which goes wrong and I am not quite sure why. Perhaps `POST` needs another http header setting in the nginx conf but login/search/register new account etc forms do work fine which also use `POST.

I am not sure if the curl statement `curl -i http://192.168.0.6:8090/tech/logout -H "Host: 192.168.0.6"` is meaningful as I cannot append the port and `/tech/` to host field as I do with `proxy_set_header Host $http_host/tech;` in the nginx conf but this is the output

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found 
Server: nginx/1.11.5
Date: Tue, 08 Nov 2016 13:20:10 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Location: http://192.168.0.6/tech/
Cache-Control: no-cache
X-Request-Id: 66707620-ebd2-4c66-af9f-3ba6633d5e7d
X-Runtime: 0.003215
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache

<html><body>You are being <a href="http://192.168.0.6/tech/">redirected</a>.</body></html>
```

So, I hope someone can shed some light on and thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging further and getting the tip from [this post](http://www.redmine.org/boards/2/topics/15325), I added the `proxy_redirect http://$host/ http://$http_host/tech/;` line to the config and it does the trick. The updated config is as below.

```
    upstream redmine-tech {
            server 10.0.2.15:8080;
    }

    server {
            listen 80 default_server;
            proxy_redirect http:// $scheme://;
            proxy_buffering off;

            location /tech {
                    rewrite ^/tech$ $scheme://$http_host/tech/ break;
                    proxy_set_header Host $http_host/tech;
                    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                    proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                    proxy_redirect http://$host/ http://$http_host/tech/;
                    #proxy_redirect    off;
                    add_header Pragma "no-cache";
                    add_header Cache-Control "no-cache";

                    proxy_pass http://redmine-tech/;
                    sub_filter 'action="/'  'action="/tech/';
                    sub_filter 'href="/'  'href="/tech/';
                    sub_filter 'src="/'  'src="/tech/';
                    sub_filter_once off;
            }
    }
```